# Why is the moon more visible during the winter?

Tags: the-moon, earth

I was curious to find out that as to why, the moon looks more sharper during the day in winter, whereas it's almost not visible during summer.

Comment: Perhaps less turbulence during clear say in winter as compared to clear day in summer. And perhaps the sun being far from your line of sight?

Comment: Where in the world are you located that you are making this observation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Air temperature range recommendation for observations in a summer night with an entry level telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/air-temperature-range-recommendation-for-observations-in-a-summer-night-with-an)

Comment: When the moon is near full, it is higher in the sky in winter than in summer, so it is shining through less atmosphere.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The answers to that question are almost entirely about viewing through a telescope (which the current question doesn't mention), and none of them offer any information at all about seasonal variation (which is the core issue in the current question). I'm voting to leave this question open.

Comment: Ranjith, please tell us what country you're in, as this is important information. For instance, in tropical and sub-tropical zones in particular the high humidity of summer reduces clarity, whereas in temperate zones the summer wildfires can affect visibility. Smog can also vary on a seasonal basis.